# Android Studio 3.1 - Logcat output has been ruined

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-studio-3.1

I upgraded my Android Studio to version 3.1

Since the update, the log message are printed in clusters.

For example, when I write

```
Log.i("Tag", "message1")  
Log.i("Tag", "message2")   
Log.i("Tag", "message3")  
Log.i("Tag", "message4")
```

Most of the time it gets printed as:

```
03-28 15:50:03.594 7057-7057/? I/Tag: message1
    message2
    message3
    message4
```

Instead of:

```
03-28 15:50:03.594 7057-7057/? I/Tag: message1
03-28 15:50:03.594 7057-7057/? I/Tag: message2
03-28 15:50:03.594 7057-7057/? I/Tag: message3
03-28 15:50:03.594 7057-7057/? I/Tag: message4
```

As it used before.

As a result, it is very difficult to filter the log.

Is anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Yeah I'd also like to know how to revert back. very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio 3.1 outputs in logcat in shorthand if TAG name appears same for multiple log statements as followiing that you have mentioned:

```
03-28 15:50:03.594 7057-7057/? I/Tag: message1
message2
message3
message4
```

Comment: Do you have any Documentation link which specify this change ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the issue tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77305804) it is fixed and is planned for Android Studio 3.2. To quote from the issue tracker:

This change in behavior was inadvertent and I reverted it. The fix will go out in 3.2.

It does not say when this version will be released. But I'll update my answer as soon as I know.